# UE4 Bluepint function Wildcard input pin

Tags: function, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I am creating a function in my bluepint which spawns something on a square tile. I want one of the input pins to be **static mesh object reference** or a **actor class reference**. In the function I then want to switch on if the input pin was a **static mesh object reference** or a **actor class reference**. Is this possible and in that case what is the variable type for this input pin called?

right now I have to create separate functions for each type of entity I want to spawn. For example SpawnMesh, SpawnLight, SpawnActor.